# Solving in positive integers an equation containing exponentials

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I stumbled upon this number theory problem while I was solving another problem. Here is the equation: $$3^kn + 3^{k-1} + 2^m(3^{k-1} + 2h) = 2^{m+l}n$$ where $k \geq 3, h,l,m,n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n$ is odd and $n$ is not a multiple of $3$. My impression is that it does not have a solution. However, I have not progressed on the problem anymore than that. Could you please help?

Thanks.

Comment: I removed the tag exponential sum because that's about the $e$ number.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [infinite descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_descent) to show that the equation does not have a solution. We know that $n= 3k+1$ for $k$ an odd integer or $n =3k+2$ for $k$ an even integer. If $(k,h,l,m,n)$ is a solution, then $2^{m+1}$ divides the LHS and $n$ divides the LHS.

Comment: it is a good suggestion but I do not yet see a way out since the coefficients of $n$ are not similar powers.

Comment: This general form of infinite descent is *equivalent* to mathematical induction (it is simply a contrapositive reformulation of it). So without any specific details, it is not saying much to speculate that induction might play some role. It does for almost all analogous problems - whether explicitly, or implicitly in various lemmas invoked.

Comment: @Bill, that is a good point.

Comment: Thanks for the link on infinite descent. Great outline.